# Conditional Split when Array for XML input Logstash

Tags: logstash

I am trying to parse a XML file and want to split. But the split field is not always array.
XML structure:

```
<A a="1">
  <B b="1" q="10">
    <C c="1" r="20"></C>
  </B>
  <B b="2" q="11">
    <C c="2" r="21"></C>
    <C c="3" r="22">
      <M m="1" />
    </C>
  <B>
</A>
```

When I try to split as

```
  xml {
    source => "message"
    target => "doc"
    force_array => false
  }      
  split {
    field => "doc[B][C]"
  }
```

I get error as Split can be done only in strings or arrays. 
How can I mutate the Strings into Array or is there another way to solve this?

Expected output:

```
{
 C => {
   c => 1,
   r => 20,
 }
 B => {
   b => 1,
   q => 10,
 }
}
{
 C => {
   c => 2,
   r => 20,
 }
 B => {
   b => 2,
   q => 11,
 }
}
{
 C => {
   c => 3,
   r => 22,
   M => {
     m => 1
   }
 }
 B => {
   b => 2,
   q => 11,
 }
}
```

Each nested  acts as a separate event and stored as a different event (row) in elastic search.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori Added.